# Selenium Chromedriver not working with Google Colab Anymore on Python 3.8.16?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory

I have been using selenium chromedriver in google colab for the past year and it seems to be working perfectly.

But last week, the script doesnt seem to be working anymore. I looked at the python version of google colab and it's now on python 3.8.16 which I think is the culprit of this code breaking.

I use the code:

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install -y chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin

from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver= webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)`
```

And now in this line:
driver= webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)

I get an error saying:
WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1

Anyone already found a fix for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75155063/selenium-use-chrome-on-colab-got-unexpectedly-exited

More people are having this problem. But so far none of the answers worked for me. Please let me know if you found a solution.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSO14hgo6Gs&ab_channel=PythonWebScraping

This tutorial worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Google-Colab-Selenium](https://github.com/jpjacobpadilla/Google-Colab-Selenium):

```
import google_colab_selenium as gs

driver = gs.Chrome()
# Your code to interact with the driver here
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with chromedriver itsself, and not python.

Also, I couldn't reproduce the error.
[image: Seems to be fine]

The execution seems to be fine for me.

You might check, if there's something else in your code which might break it and you didn't provide here.

Answer (score 0):

Run This Codes. For me it Worked

```
%%shell
# Ubuntu no longer distributes chromium-browser outside of snap
#
# Proposed solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/how-to-install-chromium-without-snap

# Add debian buster
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list <<'EOF'
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster-updates.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-security-buster.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
EOF

# Add keys
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DCC9EFBF77E11517
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 648ACFD622F3D138
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 112695A0E562B32A

apt-key export 77E11517 | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster.gpg
apt-key export 22F3D138 | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster-updates.gpg
apt-key export E562B32A | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-security-buster.gpg

# Prefer debian repo for chromium* packages only
# Note the double-blank lines between entries
cat > /etc/apt/preferences.d/chromium.pref << 'EOF'
Package: *
Pin: release a=eoan
Pin-Priority: 500


Package: *
Pin: origin "deb.debian.org"
Pin-Priority: 300


Package: chromium*
Pin: origin "deb.debian.org"
Pin-Priority: 700
EOF
```

Then Run This

```
!apt-get update
!apt-get install chromium chromium-driver
!pip3 install selenium

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "http://example.com/"
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver", options=options)
driver.get(url)
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm still getting the error, even after running your code suggestion.       WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1

Answer (score 0):

as of Oct 2023, this works on Colab:

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update 
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
url = "https://www.google.com"
driver.get(url)
print(driver.title)
```

Note that there is no 'chromedriver' input in webdriver.Chrome(options=options)